# Where is all checked out items in Tridion 2011?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

Where is the All Checked Out Items int he Tridion 2011 GUI?  In 5.3 it was in the workflow list.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its in the workflow area of 2011.

Shortcuts -> My Tasks -> Checked-out Items

Answer (score 5):

You'll want to be careful under shortcuts >  my tasks > checked out items. That can list not only your checked out items, but everyone else's . So be mindful not to check in other people's items.

Comment: Welcome and thanks for the answer @paceaux. If you haven't had a chance to check it out, consider committing to the [Area 51 Tridion StackExchange proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=V2-BIZVA0gmNn9xqeeO2NA2).